# yii2 console unknown command

Tags: yii2, console, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Trying to run function `_googleanalytics` in controller `ProcessingController`, but getting an error:

> unknown command

**`command`**:

`./yii processing/_googleanalytics '2017-02-27' '2017-02-27'`

**`controller`** path:

`/console/controllers/`

**`action`**

```
public function _googleanalytics($start, $finish) {...
```

**`controller`**

```
namespace console\controllers;
class ProcessingController extends Controller
{...
```

**`/console/config/main.php`**

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\FixtureController',
            'namespace' => 'common\fixtures',
          ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info'],
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                    'logVars' => [],
                    'categories' => ['calls'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/calls.log',
                    'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                    'maxLogFiles' => 20,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'modules'=>[
        'user-management' => [
            'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule',
            'controllerNamespace'=>'vendor\webvimark\modules\UserManagement\controllers', // To prevent yii help from crashing
        ],
        'googleanalytics' => [
           'class' => 'console\modules\googleanalytics\Module',
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you solve the problem, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an `action` to access it via console/terminal the same way as we access the actions via our browser.

For example if i create a `Test Controller` like below inside `console/controllers` directory

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;

class TestController extends \yii\console\Controller{
    public function actionIndex($param1,$param2){
        echo "\nIndex";
        echo "\n$param1 $param2\n";
    }

    public function actionMango(){
        echo "\nMango";
    }
}
```

and then type `./yii` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will show all default commands available along with the following at the end.

```
This is Yii version 2.0.14.1.

The following commands are available:
....
...
- test                             
    test/index (default)
    test/mango
```

which means it registers all the actions inside the controller as commands and if you write in the terminal the following command,

**`./yii test/index omer aslam`**

it will show you the output

```
Index
omer aslam
```

where `omer` and `aslam` are the 2 params passed to the function.

So you just need to prepend keyword `action` to your function name i would suggest using action names according to the convention, change the function from

```
public function _googleanalytics($start, $finish) {
```

to

```
public function actionGoogleanalytics($start, $finish) {
```

and then access it via

**`./yii process/googleanalytics 2017-02-27 2017-02-27`**

you can wrap with quotes but it isnt necessary to add one a space identitifies between separate params.

Hope it helps